# How To Solve Ambiguous Joomla Link

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0, joomla3.1

I still don't understand with joomla menu structure. Let say I have Categories structure like below

Category 1
   - Category 1.1
   - Category 1.2
   - Category 1.3
   - Category 1.4

Category 2
   - Category 2.1
   - Category 2.2
   - Category 2.3
   - Category 2.4

Then, I create a menu, where the structure of menu is as follow

- Home
- Category 1
  (*article >> categories*)
  -- Category 1.1
   (*article >> category blog*)
  -- Category 1.2
   (*article >> category blog*)
  -- Category 1.3
   (*article >> category blog*)
  -- Category 1.4
   (*article >> category blog*)
- Category 2
  (*article >> categories*)
  -- Category 2.1
   (*article >> category blog*)
  -- Category 2.2
   (*article >> category blog*)
  -- Category 2.3
   (*article >> category blog*)
  -- Category 2.4
   (*article >> category blog*)

So, when I create that menu, then run the joomla, let say I open Category 2 page, then joomla will show categories child of Category 2 (including with the links). However, when I open one of category child directly from the page (not from menu module), it will have different url if I open from menu module. I was recorded is as follow (just example)

- joomla2511/index.php/category-2/76-category-21.html (if I open directly from Category 2 page)
- joomla2511/index.php/category-2/category-21.html (if I open from menu module)

My question is, I don't want to use url from the page, but I want from menu module even I open it from Category 2 page.

Thanks for your advance.

Comment: What module has the bad urls?

Comment: menu module... I don't know why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same problem few months ago. As far as I remember problem is that Categories few displays links to subcategories pointing to **category articles list** when your subcategory menu item points to **category articles blog**. For Joomla those are 2 different pages thats why they have 2 different urls. Solution for this are two:

### Easy

Make every subcategory menu item pointing to category articles list

### Better

Edit categories list view so every subcategory url will point to category blog view not category articles list

Comment: I know its freaking stupid but it took me a while until I found solution ;)